# Display data in AngularJS coming in response.data

Tags: .net, angularjs

I want to display data coming in $scope.NextAccountInfo = response.data;
I am using WebAPI.
My code is as follows:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var app = angular.module('mymodulee', []);
app.controller('mycontroller', function ($scope, $http,$log) {
    $scope.ButtonClick = function () {

        $http.get('http://localhost:8080/Access/Tasks.DefectManagement/Services/Services.asmx/GetNextAccountDetails')
            .then(function(response) {
            $scope.NextAccountInfo = response.data;

            }, Error(function(reason) {
            $scope.ERROR = reason;
        })
        );
    }
});
```

Data coming in response.data is as follows:-

Object

ID:"56442"

FacilityCode:"BGHN"

**proto**:Object

length:1

**proto**:Array[0]

I want to show ID and FacilityCode.

Please Help

Thanks

Comment: To render something on browser you need at least some HTML. Show your HTML.

Comment: `NextAccountInfo.ID` should work in the html.

Comment: Response Data coming array or object ?

Comment: Its coming in Object

Comment: It is Array and array has an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just display using a dot separator

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ListCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="detail in NextAccountInfo ">
        <div>{{detail.id}} {{detail.FacilityCode}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Working [`App`](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/r5eqsaz4/2/)

Comment: How can I display alert message

Comment: @rahulaggarwal did you check?

Comment: within jquery function, if I want to get that value, not able to get output using this code.

Comment: jquery and angular? you are doing some basic thing wrong